# Unable to view versions/artifacts after upgrading Nexus to version 3.1.0-04

Tags: upgrade, nexus

I just upgraded my Sonatype Nexus instance from version 2.14-01 to 3.1.0-04.

I followed the upgrade steps and everything appeared to work correctly.

The problem I am having is I can no longer view the artifacts when I browse via explorer to my address:

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/aaa/bbb/bbb

Under Nexus 2.x, when I navigated to this path, I am able to see my versions and artifacts inside the specific version.

Is there a setting in Nexus I need to update to allow this functionality after the upgrade?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is change in the repositories location. Earlier it was content/repositories and now it is changed to repository/

To access content using old url after migration set the below property in nexus.properties.
org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.HttpBridgeModule.legacy=true

https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/install.html#config-legacy-url